# Generic Circular buffer for storing packets (structures) - C programming

Tags: c, data-structures, buffer

I am trying to implement buffer for storing packets (packets that I get from MAC layer). Basically I am implementing transmitter so I need to store some packets and then send them when transmitter is not occupied. I need advice with this part. Should I made 2 structures one which I could call buffer_pool (pool of all buffer), and another buffer_t (which would represent one buffer - packet + some additional data). What I would like to get is to be able to push and pop packets in by using FIFO. Or maybe I can do it with one structure like that below.

```
   typedef struct _buffer_t
{
    struct               _buffer_t *next;                ///< Next pointer
    volatile bool        alloc;                          ///< Alloc flag
    uint8_t              *dptr;                          ///< Data pointer - points to current position in buffer array
    uint8_t              len;                            ///< Len of the data
    uint8_t              index;                          ///< Index used for buffer tracking and debugging
    uint8_t              data[aMaxPHYPacketSize+1];       ///< Main data storage
} buffer_t;
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable, though I don't see why you need both *dptr and len?   Once you have a pointer to one of these structs, you already know where 'data' is:   '&thisStruct->data', and can get at elements: [thisStruct->data[thisStruct->len]'

Comment: @MartinJames I think you are right Martin, I just need len indeed. Thank you for suggestion. What you think should I make another structure on top of this for easier manipulation with buffers. typdef struct _buffer_pool_t { static buffer_t buf[MAX_BUF_POOL_SIZE]; uint8_t tail; uint8_t head; }

Comment: You seem to be implementing a FIFO as a linked list. Why not just as a circular buffer containing pointers? The linked list only has advantages if there is no sensible maximum on the number of packets that will exist in the FIFO at any one time.

Comment: @kdopen I decided to do it that way. So I have structure with tail and head pointers, and with data vector as array of structure. Again data vector is array of structure with boolean allocation flag and array of uint8_t. Now I am I using just pointers, and I am chacking if that part of memory is allocated or not.